# How to Consume a WebService using WSDL files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

So I have two [wsdl files](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_intro.asp) (xml based) and I need to use them to consume a web service. Not sure where to start? I'm trying to add them in my Visual Studio Project Solution by clicking on "Add Service Reference" but I need an URL.

Should I add them to a Virtual Directory? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: run `svcutil yourfile.wsdl` or `wsdl yourfile.wsdl` and add the resulting `.cs` file to your project.

Comment: You shouldn't use wsdl.exe if it's a WCF service. I recommend either using svcutil.exe or you can browse to the WSDL file through the add service UI.

Comment: @L.B your solution worked for me.  the resulting .cs goes to the svcutil directory. Ive done it to Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already found the solution. Use the "Add Service Reference" dialog and make sure your service is accessible by a URL. To do this either request the URL by the people offering the service or deploy the service in IIS.

Personally I would forget about svcutil.exe. If you have Visual Studio, it is much easier to add and update the service reference using the excellent integration of web services in Visual Studio.

Comment: How can I deploy it to the service? Like I said, I have two xml files with all the specs

Comment: As far as I understand you only have the WSDL of the service you want to consume. In order to consume a service you need both, the URL of the actual service and the WSDL!

Comment: @ZombieHunter thats not true. For security purposes a business may choose not to expose the wsdl through a URL. You can create a client using just the wsdl files.

Comment: @LeeO.: But you still need both of them, the WSDL (either as a file or a URL) and the URL of the actual service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the wsdl.exe tool which comes with Visual Studio (in there you can specify a local file path to your wsdl file) -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2s8y7bs(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Add your .wsdl address in address and click Go button.your service is add in your project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a service reference by using the path to the wsdl files.

Comment: how that can be achieved, i tried to discover from solution but that's not accessible

Comment: This is the most straight forward thing to try. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) as such:

svcutil.exe /language:cs /out:MyServiceProxy.cs /config:app.config c:\path\to\my.wsdl